LPHow do I put the springiness back into a steel rod
This is a piece of steel rod, from a clock, 100mm x 1.5mm. The mechanism is 200 years old and the steel has gone soft and lost its recoil.

Spring steels need to be worked.  Unfortunately, starting from a previously worked geometry means the result would be significantly weaker, likely snapping from lower loads if you ever get the old spring constants back.  You may have no alternative to replacing the springs while memorializing the old springs separately.

You may be able to restore this spring with a suitable heat treatment, if it is not kinked. I cannot give the exact details, but it would involve heating it uniformly to orange color, quenching in oil, and then re-tempering from red heat. Probably best to replace.
